# SOA sensors are not working in Oracle 12c

Tags: soa, sensors, jdeveloper, oracle12c

I created an application containing 4 variables with 4 sensors at variable level and one at activity level.

I deployed and executed the application instance via soa-infra, but I am not able to see any of the sensors for the same.

also there are no errors in logs for both deployment and execution.

I had done similar application in 11g and it was working perfectly.

Any clues?